# Which files/folder should be in version control for Sencha Touch 2

Tags: git, file, sencha-touch

I am building my first sencha touch 2 application. After invoking bellow command it created a `application` directory with `23M` size!

```
sencha generate app -n application`
```

I haven't added any code yet and its that big. Could you tell which file and folders should go in `git`. I dont want to add all of this. `.git` will grow huge. Some free `git` provider (bitbucket, unfuddle, beanstalk etc) will not allow that much space!

This is the current structure.

```
.
├── app
│   ├── controller
│   ├── model
│   ├── profile
│   ├── store
│   └── view
├── app.js
├── app.json
├── index.html
├── packager.json
├── resources
│   ├── css
│   ├── icons
│   ├── images
│   ├── loading
│   ├── sass
│   └── startup
└── sdk
    ├── command
    ├── microloader
    ├── resources
    ├── sencha-touch-all.js
    ├── sencha-touch.js
    ├── src
    └── version.txt
```

#### UPDATE 1:

I know generated files should not be modified. But here eventually I have to modify some generated files too. Also there are some generated files which I dont need to modify at all (e.g. `sdk` directory). Now I want to know what are the other entities like `sdk` that I never need to modify so I can just put them in `.gitignore`.

Answer (score 1):

Any part of that structure that can be generated should not be part of your git repo and added to a `.gitignore` file.

You can see many examples of `.gitignore` files in the [GitHub gitignore project](https://github.com/github/gitignore).

Comment: I know that rule.  But here eventually I have to modify some generated files too. Also there are some generated files which I dont need to modify for any reason (e.g. 'sdk'). Now I want to know what are the other entities like `sdk` that I never need to modify so I can just .gitignore them

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im note that, for the generated files you need to modify, you would version a script able to modify said generated files, you wouldn't version generated files.